# Singleton and Synchronised Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, singleton

I want to create a Servlet that processes input to a serial device and for that reason I want to make sure that exactly one instance of Servlet exists in the container at a time (irrespective of whether the container makes only one instance I have to make sure of it) and also the access to the serial port is either synchronised or serialised.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you have several instances of the Servlet, but only one serving a request at a time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the servlet to be a singleton, you only need to be able to control access to the serial port. In fact even if you could enforce a single instance of the servlet class, the spec enables multiple users to access the servlet concurrently.

You could instead write a class that handles access to the port, encapsulating control by only allowing a single thread to access at a time. You'd then need to decide how you wanted concurrent requests to the servlet to behave (block, return some sort of 'serial port in use' error message, etc).

Comment: in fact, the servlet IS singleton always. The spec guarantees that.

Comment: @Bozho could you provide a reference please? My [spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-2.4-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) says, *The use of the `SingleThreadModel` interface guarantees that only one thread at a time will execute in a given servlet instance’s service method. It is important to note that this guarantee only applies to each servlet instance, since the container may choose to pool such objects.* — that is, at least for some cases it it not true.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: don't do that. Leave servlet management to the container, and use your own singleton for serial port processing.

Solution: you cannot, as you have no control over constructor. What you can do, though, (and what is a Very Bad Thing—don't tell anyone I said that) is to have a static field in a servlet, keeping a reference to the first instantiated instance. This way, all the instances of the servlet will be able to delegate the processing to this very first instance.

Again, just separating request processing from serial port processing will make things much more easier for both you and the container.